# jQuery: does using .html(html) replace current content

Tags: jquery

When I do something like:

```
$.post("update.php", {page: $(this).attr('data-page')}, function(success){
            $("#dialog").html(html);
        }
});
```

and I have a :

```
<div id="dialog" style="display: block;">

     //a bunch of html in here, initially it's not empty
 </div>
```

Then will that `$("#dialog").html(html);` replace all the bunch of html that initially we have or does it append to it?

Comment: Didn't you try it and find out?

Comment: Or read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) will replace the content.

Use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add to the existing content.

Answer (score 1):

It replaces the content.  If you want to append it, you can call ".append()":

```
 $('#dialog').append(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

It will replace it. Note that you should write:

```
 $("#dialog").html(success);
```

if you want to append the data, use:

```
 $("#dialog").append(success);
```

Simple, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is in your success (hopefully html) should be appended:

```
$.post("update.php", {page: $(this).attr('data-page')}, function(success){
        $("#dialog").append(success);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that existing content will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

It will replace all the html.
To append use:

```
$("#dialog").append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will overwrite the contents of the `#dialog` element with your `html` parameter.  If you just want to add it to the end, use the [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method: `append(html)`.

Answer (score 0):

from jQuery doc: When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new Content.

So it replaces old content